# Grails project don't run after CloudFoundry

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

Today I deployed my test project on cloud foundry. and there is no any problems, app was worked nice. but after I stoped the cloud foundry I want to run the app localy with comand grails run-app, but I get this error message:

```
Error /path/to/my/app/app-name does not appear to be part of a Grails application.
```

any ideas what does it mean?

EDIT!
When I run the app from terminal via command run-app everything is ok, but when I click the Run button in the STS i get the error!

EDIT!
It's working. i'm just refreshing the dependencies with right click on app Grails Tools -> Refresh Dependencies or Alt+G R

Answer (score 1):

refreshing the dependencies will work. (right click on app Grails Tools -> Refresh Dependencies or Alt+G R)